# Veracode gives XSS error when numbers are being cast to double in Coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, veracode

The following Coldfusion code was tested by Static code analyzer Veracode.com:

```
<cfloop from="1" to="3" index="kontakt_idx">
    <tr class="rowclass#htmleditformat(kontakt_idx +1)#">
        <td>..</td>
    </tr>
</cfloop>
```

I get the result:

```
Attack Vector: coldfusion.runtime.Cast._double
Description: This call to coldfusion.runtime.Cast._double() contains a cross-site scripting (XSS) flaw.
```

Veracode does not scan the Coldfusion code itself. It has to be precompiled with a tool Adobe provides. The results I see on the Veracode website however gives line numbers that are correct. I therefore doubt I'm a being pointed to a wrong line. I put the `HTMLEditFormat()` after I got first scan results back, but the error remains.

How could this code result in XSS? How could a call to `coldfusion.runtime.Cast._double` result in XSS at all? Coldfusion throws an exception when an invalid value is being cast to double.
I got a similar error when I was using a Form-scope variable. There, in some cases I could simply replace the use of Form. On another occurence of `cfloop from to` I got result `Attack Vector: coldfusion.runtime.Cast._int`. Why does Veracode sometimes claim there's a cast to double and sometimes a cast to int?

I'm absolutely unsure what I should do about it in this case. What could I do when a variable from Form scope is used in a calculation - firstly to secure my application, secondly to satisfy Veracode.

Comment: I'd contact them and see if it's a false positive.

Comment: Boss asked to solve as many flaws as possible to keep the number of false positives to report small. Simply because they have to be reported and explained after every rescan.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to contact Veracode support, but in this case I think the issue is in the ColdFusion implementation rather than your code.

Older versions of ColdFusion had an error page for certain exception types that was *itself* vulnerable to XSS. So what's going on in your code is that the code triggered the exception, not that the cast itself was an XSS error.

Veracode support can review the code in question and verify that that's what's going on, but that's my best guess as to why the engine might have flagged this error.